# cannot see certificate under settings in cloudfront distribution despite adding valid arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

In cloudfront I have a distribution, and when I click on 'edit' under settings, I have put in the arn of a validated certificate (created through ACM). However, when I save and go back to the settings of the cloudfront distribution, I cannot see the heading "Custom SSL Certificate" and the link to the certificate is not visible - does anyone know what else I  need to do to see the certificate link under the Custom SSL Certificate heading (in addition to editing and adding the certificate arn)?

Comment: Is the ACM cert in us-east-1?

Comment: Have you added one or more alternate domain names / CNAMEs to your distribution? Those are required to see an attached certificate on the distribution details page.

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this page:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-ssl-cloudfront/

"How do I configure my CloudFront distribution to use an SSL/TLS certificate?"

If you use an Amazon issued certificate:

- You must request the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) Region.
- You must have permission to use and request the ACM certificate.

If you use an imported certificate with CloudFront:

- Your key length must be 1024 or 2048 bits and cannot exceed 2048 bits.
- You must import the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) Region.
- You must have permission to use and import the SSL/TLS certificate.